# php pop up box after if statement?

Tags: php, facebook

I am doing some php to make an app and i need a window to pop up when i run my php if statement. At the minute, when i run the app, my if statement works, but goes to a new page to display the info from my if statement. How would i change my echo to have a box pop up with the message instead?

Hope that makes sense.

my if statement:

```
<?php

$status = $_POST['status'];

if($status == "")

echo "Please enter a status.";

else {

echo "Thanks.";

}


?>
```

again, just to clarify, i would like my echo statements to be a pop up message box instead, i tried to use alert but that threw errors, i have looked around but cant seem to find a php pop up box.

Comment: PHP runs on the server and then delivers the content to the user. The only way the User can input something back to the server is through a GET or POST request. You will not be able to pop-up/alert from PHP and have the user insert a value then. Instead you will need to use PHP to detect the missing variable, output a HTML/Javascript popup and then have that post the value back to the PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP and javascript, you can alert something like this:

```
<?php

    $status = $_POST['status'];

    if($status == "")

        $msg = "Please enter a status.";

    else {

        $msg = "Thanks.";

    }


?>
<script>
    alert('<? echo $msg; ?>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is more of a "server side" language that runs business logic. If you want a popup you will have to do it with javascript.

Perhaps something like the following:

```
<?php
$status = $_POST['status'];

if($status == "")

?>

<script>
alert("Please enter a status.");
</script>

<?php

else {

echo "Thanks.";

}

?>
```